# Como ler conteúdo de um site em javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria de saber como faço para ler conteúdo de outras paginas da web utilizando apenas javascript ou alguma biblioteca.

Por exemplo, de um site de noticias remoto, no caso: www.terra.com.br.

E eu gostaria de criar uma webapp para ler as últimas notícias apresentadas nessa pagina, sendo que a mesma não tem RSS e etc.

Eu sei dos problemas que poderiam ocorrer caso as paginas que eu estou me alimentando mude o layout ou qualquer coisa do tipo.

Teria alguma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Para qual SO? Tem que ser webapp mesmo?

Comment: tanto faz o SO né? Posso fazer uma pagina web e rodar em algum webview.

Comment: Era essa minha dúvida, se era pra algum específico ou pra todos.

Comment: ahh ok, tudo certo :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pode fazer diretamente uma requisição AJAX para o servidor, assim:

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var html = xmlhttp.responseText;
        processPage(html);
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://www.terra.com.br/", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Note que dependendo do servidor você pode ter problemas com requisições cross-origin. Uma forma simples de burlar isso é usar um serviço como o **[whateverorigin.org](http://whateverorigin.org/)**. Nesse caso fica assim:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=" + 
                    encodeURIComponent("http://www.terra.com.br/"), true);
```

Comment: ok perfeito... mas como faço para manipular o conteúdo? No caso eu quero copiar conteúdo de alguma DIV e colocar no meu webapp por exemplo, todo conteúdo da Div de notícias.

Comment: Outro site que também permite isso é o http://www.corsproxy.com/, a forma de utilizar ele é, inclusive, mais fácil. `xmlhttp.open('GET', 'http://crosproxy.com/www.terra.com.br/'), true);`

Comment: @ArilsonCarmo Implemente a sua `processPage()`. Lá você pode usar algum parser de html ou (se for algo muito simples, não recomendo) usar regex mesmo. Depende do que você quer extrair.

Comment: No caso eu queria extrair todos os filmes deste endereço http://www.jcnet.com.br/cinema.php, pegar a imagem e os horarios. Você teria algum JSFiddle de exemplo? Se puder é claro.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Estamos falando de Javascript, não de outra linguagem. Extrair HTML de um texto é questão de duas linhas em javascript.

Comment: Note que inserir o html no DOM para fazer o navegador o processar por você vai causar execução de scripts e afins. Não é uma boa solução.

Comment: Sim exatamente! javascript que estamos falando! Quero extrair TODO conteúdo da pagina e manipular. Eu não entendi como eu faço isso... OK.. faço a requisição Ajax consigo ter a html e o resto? Por exemplo como eu pego um determinado conteúdo de uma tag?

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Ele não executa enquanto não inserir na DOM, mas processa. // Me lembrei agora: primeira versão de um site meu fiz usando isso. Dica: não use, uma mudança no site e seu programa para.

Comment: tá.. mas não vi uma forma de manipular o conteúdo... requisição ajax? ok. Mas como faço para manipular o que eu realmente preciso?

Comment: Olhe o exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/TG8Bm/

Comment: BTW andei pesquisando como que o jQuery lida com strings de HTML sem processar os scripts: [`.parseHTML`](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.parseHTML), [`.buildFragment`](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.buildFragment). É semelhante ao meu exemplo, só que usando `documentFragment`s e com resolução de bugs.

Comment: Nossa tava olhando agora... que coisa horrível é a página...Eu não sei se a parte cinema é um iframe ou o que que é.. mas não consigo extrair o conteudo... da forma que você fez está muito correto... obrigado... mas teria que ser do conteudo cinema.php... e não vai! Bizarro!

Comment: ah entendi o que eles fizeram... cada filme novo é uma table '-'

Comment: vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13351/discussion-between-arilson-carmo-and-gustavo-rodrigues)